# I can't execute rspec using 'bundle exec rspec'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, bundler

I'm very new to coding and I have been learning ruby through the app academy open bootcamp. I have gotten to the Rspec topic, but after installing the gems from the gem file provided in the course:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "byebug"
gem "rspec", "~> 3.2.0"
```

The next step was to run Rspec using `bundle exec rspec` and I keep getting this error

```
from C:/Users/USER/Desktop/App Academy/rspec_demo/spec/add_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Users/USER/Desktop/App Academy/rspec_demo/spec/add_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm using windows 10
ruby version 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233)
rails version 6.1.4
gem version 3.2.22

I have tried uninstalling then reinstalling ruby on rails, and reinstalling the gem files. I have tried Googling the solution but I can not find a single solution for my specific problem. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the entire error message. You skipped at least one crucial line at the top.

Comment: And please post the content of the `App Academy/rspec_demo/spec/add_spec.rb:1` - especially the first line because that is where the exception is raised.

Comment: Especially for someone new to coding - I would strongly advise learning (pure) Ruby before learning Rails.

Comment: After editing the Gemfile, did you run `bundle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t know if YMMV on windows but I think the things you’re missing are

```
$ bundle install
```

And

```
$ rspec init
```

Read up on those

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I have been so busy lately. I read up on $ bundle install and $ rspec like you said, and decided to run the whole process all over again from the start and it finally worked this time, thank you so much for the help

Comment: Please hit the upvote button if this helped @Mthunzi